# How to Add and Use key in Custom widget constructors

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, flutter-widget

I got notification warning (Not Error) about `Use key in widget constructors.` let say I have stateless class like this :

```
class TeaTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final TheTea? tea;
  const TeaTile({this.tea});  //the warning in hire!

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

the basic stateless format has a key like this :

```
class TeaTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const TeaTile({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);  //this one

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I know how to disable the key rule `use_key_in_widget_constructors: false`. but I don't want to do it. so, how I add `key` in

```
final TheTea? tea;
  const TeaTile({this.tea});
```

to solve the warning notification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update for Dart 2.17 using Super Initializers:**

```dart
final TheTea? tea;
const TeaTile({ super.key, this.tea });
```

The `super` keyword in a constructor is a shortcut for the method below.

**Older Dart versions:**

```dart
final TheTea? tea;
const TeaTile({ Key? key, this.tea }) : super(key: key);
```

Basically a combination of both, you're still taking a named parameter `key`, that will pass it's value to the super constructor, and another named parameter `tea` that would set your final variable value.